# Service Account OAuth2 for Provisioning api

Tags: oauth, google-api-java-client, google-provisioning-api

Does the service account OAuth2 authentication work for the Provisioning api. I have a google apps admin account and need to manage all accounts through the desktop application. Is this possible using the Service Account authentication mechanism for OAuth 2.0. Can i pull and push details of all user accounts created on the particular domain?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, service account doesn't work for Provisioning API.  However, it does work for admin sdk, which is the new API that's replacing the provisioning API!

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/